# Recursive update for tree structure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

I have the following structure of table.

```
id     chNum        parentid 
---    ------       --------- 
1        1            NULL
2        1.1          1
3        1.1.1        2
4        2            NULL  (Here add the new row) 
5        3            NULL
6        4            NULL
```

After added new row in between the rows, this and all the following rows (based on `chNum`) should change.

Result as follows:

```
id     chNum        parentid 
---    ------       --------- 
1        1            NULL
2        1.1          1
3        1.1.1        2
4        2            NULL  
7        3            NULL --\
5        4            NULL -- + -- these rows are changed
6        5            NULL --/
```

Is this possible to use recursive update SQL query in pl/pgsql and is this best way for faster data update than through application side?

Sample scenarios for "chNum" auto update:

[image]

Comment: I don't see here the need for recursion.  But there is an other problem: what if a value to be changed is in the form of 3.3 or 2.3.4?

Comment: Yes. Possible. If I add as parent, shows the above example. As you said, its possible to add as child like "From 2 to 2.1, 2.2, 2.3...."

Comment: What I mean is that if the row with the ID 5 contained 3.3 instead of 3, what should it change to?  And what should happen when you insert a new child?

Comment: Here ID is unique not changed. If insert a row as parent "ChNum" column automatically increased. The same time, if delete any row, that time also "chNum" automatically rearranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd came to a solution that uses a trigger to manage the updates properly. To make things better and easier, I added the column `chpath` that is an array of integer, to keep the value presented by you as `chnum`. This seems more reasonable to me, as we can order by it correctly (which cannot be done with string, at least no without some treatment) and also is easier to manipulate.

So, I came to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE chapters (
    id serial primary key,
    chnum text,
    parentid integer,
    chpath integer[]
);
```

Now to the problem...

The following trigger function is capable of managing the insert and delete of rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tg_chapters()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_head int[];
    v_len int;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_WHEN = 'BEFORE' AND (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE')) THEN
        /* Update chnum field (string representation of chpath) */
        NEW.chnum = array_to_string(NEW.chpath, '.');
    END IF;
    IF (TG_WHEN = 'AFTER' AND TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
        v_len := array_length(OLD.chpath, 1);
        /* Get the chapters with same head and DECREMENT the last level */
        UPDATE chapters c
        SET chpath = c.chpath[1:(v_len-1)]||(c.chpath[v_len]-1)||c.chpath[(v_len+1):array_upper(c.chpath,1)]
        WHERE
            c.id <> OLD.id
            AND c.chpath >= OLD.chpath
            AND c.chpath[1:v_len] <> OLD.chpath
            AND array_length(c.chpath,1) >= v_len;
        /* Delete the children */
        DELETE FROM chapters c WHERE c.parentid = OLD.id;
    END IF;
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
        IF (TG_WHEN = 'BEFORE') THEN
            v_head := NEW.chpath[1:(array_upper(NEW.chpath,1)-1)];
            /* BEFORE: update chpath and parentid */
            IF (v_head = '{}'::int[]) THEN
                NEW.parentid = null;
            ELSE
                SELECT c.id INTO STRICT NEW.parentid FROM chapters c WHERE c.id <> NEW.id AND c.chpath = v_head;
            END IF;
        ELSIF (TG_WHEN = 'AFTER') THEN
            v_len := array_length(NEW.chpath, 1);
            /* AFTER: get the chapters with same head and INCREMENT the last level */
            UPDATE chapters c
            SET chpath = c.chpath[1:(v_len-1)]||(c.chpath[v_len]+1)||c.chpath[(v_len+1):array_upper(c.chpath,1)]
            WHERE
                c.id <> NEW.id
                AND c.chpath >= NEW.chpath
                AND array_length(c.chpath,1) >= v_len;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;
```

And the triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_chapters_after
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
ON chapters
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tg_chapters();
CREATE TRIGGER tg_chapters_before
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF chpath
ON chapters
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tg_chapters();
```

It only uses the `chpath`, so the insert must use it properly, and you should always insert into a valid position (e.g. it does not treat gaps). It could be improved to provide some constraints. Also, don't try bulk insert or bulk delete, because this trigger expect the rows to be inserted/deleted in the correct order.

Now, about the lack of update, if you really need an UPDATE you can:

1. Try to improve the trigger with some kind of flag column;
2. Use DELETE followed by INSERT instead of an UPDATE (inside a transaction, of course).

The first seems a little hard at first glance and error prone. The second is simple and works well, to avoid unusual operations on the application side you could create a view to this table (and use only it) that handle the INSERT/DELETE (just issue them on the real table) and UPDATE (do DELETE + INSERT on the real table).

Samples at **[this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/08f78/1)**.

Comment: BTW, if someone (@dezso ?) have a better an idea about the update, I'd like to read... =D

Comment: Thanks lot @MatheusOl...few things confirm is it possible. One is: chNum order should be incremental order. like 1.1,1.2,1.3... Not jump to 1.1, 1.4 like that. Is this possible ? Second one is: is possible to move row between list. For e.g: {4} move to {1.3}. I want keep primary key number. bocz I have related data with this number.

Comment: @gnabhan: First, with this implementation `chNum` doesn't jump, unless I made some mistake on the implementation, could you show a case it may happen? Second, this works, but not with `UPDATE`, see the [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/08f78/3) (before the last command)

Comment: I'm Sorry MatheusOl for misunderstood. Jump means, in the list ({1},{1.1},{1.2}). If I try to insert chpath(1,4), either insert as {1.3} or don't allow if not in order. Second one, got it. Really nice... thanks lot !!!

Answer (score 3):

First, lets try to generate the `chnum` column using a recursive query (without using the generated, of course):

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT c.id, c.parentid, ARRAY[row_number() OVER(ORDER BY c.id)] AS chnum
        FROM chapters c
        WHERE c.parentid IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.id, c.parentid, array_append(r.chnum, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.parentid ORDER BY c.id)) AS chnum
        FROM chapters c JOIN r ON c.parentid = r.id
)
SELECT r.id, array_to_string(r.chnum, '.') AS chnum, parentid FROM r
ORDER BY r.chnum;
```

Now, we just need to take this result and update every `id` that doesn't match the `chnum`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT c.id, c.parentid, ARRAY[row_number() OVER(ORDER BY c.id)] AS chnum
        FROM chapters c
        WHERE c.parentid IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT c.id, c.parentid, array_append(r.chnum, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.parentid ORDER BY c.id)) AS chnum
        FROM chapters c JOIN r ON c.parentid = r.id
)
UPDATE chapters c
SET chnum = array_to_string(r.chnum, '.')
FROM r
WHERE c.chnum IS DISTINCT FROM array_to_string(r.chnum, '.') AND c.id = r.id;
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7ed55/1) that I used to test it.

I'm making some assumptions here:

1. The `id` column is primary key.
2. The order is defined by the `id` column, probably a `pos` column or `after/before` thing would be better.

Also, unless it is a really huge table, I wouldn't store the `chnum` result, instead I'd create a view with the first query and just use it on the code.

Comment: Your second assumption is wrong (if the data in the questions are).  Check the ID 7.  Nevertheless, I think your idea could be adapted to fit this, just first the parents should be updated where the chnum is equal or greater to the one to be inserted.

Comment: @dezso, I know the second assumption is wrong, but the OP didn't say what define the order, I sent a example that the OP should adapt for its case or explain better here (for us to improve the answer). About the update, I agree, that is a good idea to add this filter on recursive clause if used on a trigger, but again, we need to know what defines the order to do this.

Comment: I think the order is defined by `chnum` itself (see the position of the inserted row).

Comment: thanks @MatheusOl. My case, **chnum** dynamically change. How I could insert new row inside list.

Comment: @gnabhan: as dezso pointed, seems the problem is harder then I thought... So, using my approach you should use an auxiliary column to define the order... I have an idea without this need, let me elaborate it and put another answer...